# Conditionally controlling values in a sum

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
| id   | c1  | c2   | c3    |
|------|-----|------|-------|
| 1334 | 20  | 3565 | 0.005 |
| 1335 | 543 | 2100 | 0.205 |
```

`c3` is calculated by doing `c1 / (c1 + c2)` like so:

```
agg = (
    df1
    .groupby('id')
    .agg(
        F.count('c1').alias('c1'),
        F.count('c2').alias('c2')
    )
).withColumn('c3',
             F.col('c1') / (F.col('c1') + F.col('c2')))
```

I would like to conditionally alter the values in my `.withColumn` like so:

```
if c1 < 50 then 0
if c2 > 1000 then 1000
```

So for `id` 1334, the calculation becomes `0 / (0 + 1000)` and for `id` 1335 it becomes `545 / (543 + 1000)`.

I had tried using `.when()` but cannot seem to get the syntax correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
.withColumn(
    'c3',
    F.when(F.col('c1') < 50, 0).otherwise(F.col('c1')) / (
        F.when(F.col('c1') < 50, 0).otherwise(F.col('c1')) +
        F.when(F.col('c2') > 1000, 1000).otherwise(F.col('c2'))
    )
)
```